# Is there a way to rerun all Pytest tests when a file is saved?

Tags: pytest

Is there a way to automatically re-run all tests with Pytest if a file is saved in the project?

This is essentially [Jest's --watch and --watchAll flags](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#:%7E:text=name%2Dof%2Dspec-,Run%20watch%20mode%3A,-jest%20%2D%2Dwatch%20%23runs), which respectively reruns the designated test file and all test files whenever any files are saved.

Does [PyTest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/contents.html) have a similar function or flag?

Comment: This does not answer your question but... Once your code base grows the amount of time and resources it takes to re-run all your tests will start becoming undesirable. My last project might have been 20k lines and it took 2-3 minutes to run every test. Do you really need that when you're only working on "hopefully" a single function or module? I don't find it that difficult to open of the test runner and run all the tests for a single file/function/module/class? If you set up your pull requests up all your tests should run when you attempt to commit and fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not too late, I have just found out about pytest-xdist

You can install it with `$ pip install pytest-xdist`

And run the test watcher with `$ pytest -f` and it looks at your directory and runs the test when files change.

More info here https://pytest-xdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pytest-watcher` tool (I'm the author).

It listens for various file events (change, add, delete, move) using OS native APIs. By default it looks for changes in `*.py` files (customizable).

Install it with pip:

```bash
pip install pytest-watcher
```

Then start `pytest-watcher` in your project folder:

```
ptw .
```

For more information, visit the GitHub page:
https://github.com/olzhasar/pytest-watcher